# How to stop express from matching more than one route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, backend

Matching for routes doesn't stop after the first one is matched, a similar problem to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70768324/why-is-express-matching-two-routes), but the solution wasn't provided there.

The problem: **When I navigate to the root of the website in the browser, the connection is made to both of the routes** (the second connection is a favicon request to the second route). This doesn't happen if I declare all my routes is a single file so I'm assuming it's got something to do with `app.use()`.

In the `index.js` file (entry point) I am importing my routes this way:

index.js:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const index = require('./backend/pages/index')
const page = require('./backend/pages/page')
app.use('/', index)
app.use('/:pageId/', page)

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${3000}`)
})
```

Both of my routes have the same code:

```js
const express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router()

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(`got a request ${Math.random()}`)
    return res.send('something')
})

module.exports = router
```

This is the most minimal and reproducible sample I can provide

I tried to fix this in so many ways I don't even remember every combination of code I tried. Any of the provided solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059246/how-to-include-route-handlers-in-multiple-files-in-express) don't seem to work.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) incl. curl requests.

Comment: @Marc this code is easily reproducible for anyone who knows the basics of express, I don't know what else can be needed as I explained the whole structure and provided examples. No fancy curl requests are needed, the bug happens upon simple browser navigation to the page

Comment: You're probably just catching a request to `favicon.ico`. Try logging `req.originalUrl`. Express cannot route to multiple handlers unless the first match calls `next()`

Comment: @phil indeed, that was favicon, thanks. I could disregard this, but this route makes a database call and I want to optimize my code as most as possible. How should I solve this problem? (just checked, I'm also catching .css requests)

Comment: I just checked, there's a request to `/` and `/favicon.ico` which is handled by the former route? I don't understand this behavior. Why is the favicon request made to the second route? This causes unnecessary calls to my database

Comment: Add static middleware for assets like `favicon.ico` and CSS files

Comment: Isn't this like applying a patch to a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place? When I declare all my routes in one single file none of this happens. Is this how everyone does this? @Phil

Comment: A page typically fetches a lot of files with multiple extensions, I might add. A blacklist shouldn't be the solution

Comment: In my opinion, routes like `/:pageId` are a code smell. They're far too permissive, basically a catch-all. At the very least, use a prefix like `/page/:pageId`